# Nexus One and High Quality youtube video

Tags: android, youtube-api, nexus-one

From our android app I launch Youtube app with the proper video id. This works well across all devices. On Nexus One the youtube app defaults to using low quality video. I have added &fmt=18 in the url (for eg: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsjadfLYnD4&feature=youtube_gdata&fmt=18 , see this blog for details http://blog.jimmyr.com/High_Quality_on_Youtube_11_2008.php) which should have forced a high quality video but doesn't.

Anyone know a work around for this ? The screen resolution on nexus is really beautiful it saddens me that I can't make use of this to play hq videos.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with a setting inside the OS itself.

[High Quality Youtube Mobile](http://www.nexusoneforum.net/forum/nexus-one-general-discussion/976-high-quality-youtube-mobile.html)

[Make Youtube Default High Quality](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-hacks/9975-make-youtube-default-high-quality.html)

Comment: I feared as much, so sad, such a waste.